# Matching *.jpg but not *.foo.jpg in bash

Tags: bash, glob

This must be simple but I can't figure it out.

```
for filename in *[^\.foo].jpg
do
echo $filename
done
```

Instead of the matched filenames, `echo` shows the pattern:

```
+ echo '*[^.foo].jpg'
*[^.foo].jpg
```

Intention is to find all files ending in `.jpg` but not `.foo.jpg`.

**EDIT:** Tried this as per (misunderstood) advice:

`for filename in *[!".foo"].jpg`

Still not there!

Comment: Are you sure that `[^...]` is valid `bash` syntax?

Comment: add some sample filenames for 1. files you expect to match, 2. files you don't want to match. Is your use of `[^...]` meant to be a negation of the char class? In shell, you use `[!...]`, and read about what I mean by character class. Good luck.

Comment: That's not a valid shell glob. What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: ...right now, we have to guess what your meaning -- since your code doesn't mean anything to the shell, how can it be expected to mean anything to us? :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, well, it seems straightforward buggy `sed` pseudocode:D Probably `anything-notdotfoo-dotjpg`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Find all files ending in `.jpg` but not `.foo.jpg`

Comment: @Jortstek, have you considered calling `sed` or something to parse your filenames, choosing only those which you need?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, `sed` is the wrong tool -- it works on lines, but filenames can't be safely represented in a newline-delimited file, since newlines are valid inside filenames.

Comment: @Jortstek, why don't you edit that clarification of your expected behavior into the question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, true, thanks. I'd like to use my "... or something" card to migrate to...`perl`? Or something;)

Comment: @Jortstek, ...to be clear about why you get the behavior you see: Square brackets define a character class. A character class, by definition, matches *exactly one character* -- not multiple characters, like an extension.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Clarification added. From reading this I thought that the caret negation was allowed http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: @Jortstek, the ABS is a very poor reference; I strongly advise against using it. The Wooledge BashGuide and wiki are far more focused on accuracy and good practices; the bash-hackers wiki, as well. With respect to negation inside character classes, it is allowed, but the operator is `!`, not `^`.

Comment: ...though in bash, `^` does indeed work; that's an extension beyond POSIX, however, which only requires `!`. Still moot, though, because it's character class inversion, not negative lookahead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that also means that you can't fix this by parenthesizing some characters in `[^...]`, right?

Comment: @Jortstek, if you thought I was advising you to use `*[!".foo"].jpg`, you weren't reading carefully enough. I never gave that advice.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, correct.

Comment: BTW, editing solutions into the question text isn't generally considered good practice here; SO has its own methods to display answers, which allow both the OP's selection of an answer and community voting on same to be reflected.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Edited out. Including the thanks to you, which were heartfelt but superfluous, yes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually **can** do this, with an extglob. To demonstrate, copy-and-paste the following code:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd "$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/test.XXXXXX")" || exit
touch hello.txt hello.foo hello.foo.jpg hello.jpg
printf '%q\n' !(*.foo).jpg
```

Output should be:

```
hello.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to loop thru the files? I need to do stuff on them.

Comment: @Jortstek, you can use `!(*.foo).jpg` in a loop just fine. `for f in !(*.foo).jpg; do`, etc. Commands don't get their own special glob syntax -- if a glob works in one place (like on `printf`'s command line), it'll work elsewhere (in a `for` loop).

Comment: @Jortstek, ...note that you still need the `shopt -s extglob`, to enable the shell feature.

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token `(for filename in !(*.foo).jpg;

Comment: @Jortstek, then you didn't enable `extglob`, or you have too old a version of bash.

Comment: @Jortstek, ...to be clear, this is tested against 4.3.18

Comment: Correct. Works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, if a glob pattern has no matches bash will return the pattern itself. You can change this behavior with the `nullglob` shell option, which can be turned on like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This is described in the section titled [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) in the bash man page.

As to why it doesn't match, it's simply that you don't have any files that match. This is possibly due to your use of `^` which isn't normally a valid glob meta character. As far as glob is concerned, `^` simply matches a literal `^`. Also, `[...]` probably doesn't do what you think it does either.

For an explanation of valid glob meta-characters, see the [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) section of the bash man page.

You can't write a glob pattern that returns "all files ending in .jpg but not .foo.jpg.". The easiest thing to do is glob over all jpg files (`*.jpg`) and then filter out the ones that end in `foo.jpg` inside the code block.

```
for filename in *.jpg
do
    [[ $filename = *.foo.jpg ]] && continue
    echo $filename
done
```

Comment: That's not the only thing that's wrong -- the character class obviously has a meaning different than what the OP intends (as there's no point in writing `[^.foo]` rather than the exact semantic equivalents `[^.fo]` or `[.of^]`).

Comment: ...anyhow, `^` is every bit as valid as any other collating character is, which is to say, it represents itself. If a negation is needed, then yes, that needs to be `!` instead... but given the context, I find that doubtful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you are correct. I've rephrased my answer with respect to `^`.

Comment: Negation *is* needed. Substituting the ^ for ! doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There are definitely matches.

Comment: @Jortstek, that's because of the underlying problem -- you want to tell it not to match a string, but it's a character class; it matches one character. That's an entirely different thing from a negative lookahead match, which is what you want it to be. The `!` still doesn't make it a negative lookahead match, it just changes the list of characters it matches to be ones *not* in its contents.

Comment: @Jortstek: there may be matches to what you _want_ to match, there definitely aren't matches according to your pattern and the rules of glob.

Comment: Thanks to you both for all the useful tips! Much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the `==` to `=` to encourage POSIX-compliant habits. :)

Comment: Might also change `echo $filename` to `echo "$filename"`, or still better `printf '%s\n' "$filename"`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo re: the first proposed substitution, and the POSIX `echo` spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html (particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections) re: the latter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I left `echo $filename` in because that's what's in the OP's question, and isn't relative to what was asked. Too many changes might lead the OP to believe that the lack of quotes around `$filename` was part of the specific problem being asked about rather than a separate problem.  I understand it's important to use good coding standards in answers, but it's also important for the reader to easily understand what caused their immediate problem. Thanks for all of the comments, though.

Comment: @BryanOakley Charles had the right answer but in the end I went with yours. As you hinted, doing the test command ([[]]) inside the loop means no need to enable `extglob` or `nullglob`. Less breakable. Thanks again.